# Makefile commands conditional on file existing

Tags: unix, makefile, latex

I have a number of latex files, and I want to be able to compile them all conveniently.  My makefile is currently as follows.

```
targets := $(patsubst %.tex, %.pdf, $(wildcard *.tex))
.PHONY: all

all: $(targets)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.pdf: %.tex $$(wildcard $$*_inc/*.*)
    pdflatex $<
```

This way, if an include folder exists, everything within that folder will be treated as a dependency.

However, I also want to automate the running of dependent python scripts.  These might be the creation of plots or the calculation of values to be included.  I attempted to make the following modification.

```
targets := $(patsubst %.tex, %.pdf, $(wildcard *.tex))

all: $(targets)
.PHONY: all run_%

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.pdf: %.tex $$(wildcard $$*_inc/*.*) $$(patsubst %, run_%, $$(wildcard $$*_inc/*.py))
    pdflatex $<

run_%: %
    $<
```

However, this does not work as I would expect to.  I have the following folder structure.

```
|
|-Makefile
|-paper.tex
|-paper_inc/
|---a.txt
|---b.py
```

I would expect this to run `b.py`, then run `pdflatex paper.tex`.  However, `b.py` is not run.  If I look at the dependencies created, I see that `paper_inc/a.txt` and `paper_inc/b.py` are dependencies of `paper.pdf`, but `run_paper_inc/b.py` is not.

I'm not entirely certain what is the issue with this, as it feels that it should work.  In addition, I tried the following lines as well for the `%.pdf` rule.

```
%.pdf: %.tex $$(wildcard $$*_inc/*.*) $$(addprefix run_,$$(wildcard $$*_inc/*.py))
%.pdf: %.tex $$(wildcard $$*_inc/*.*) $$(shell ls $$*_inc/*.py | sed 's/^/run/')
%.pdf: %.tex $$(wildcard $$*_inc/*.*) $$(shell ls $$*_inc/*.py | awk '{print "prefix "$0}')
```

With each of these rules, though, I receive the error message `make: *** No rule to make target 'paper.pdf'.  Stop.`

What should be be done to fix this error, or, alternatively, what should I use instead of `make`?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

**First:**

```
run_%: %
    $<
```

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match):

> When the target pattern does not contain a slash (and it usually does
>   not), directory names in the file names are removed from the file name
>   before it is compared with the target prefix and suffix. After the
>   comparison of the file name to the target pattern, the directory
>   names, along with the slash that ends them, are added on to the
>   prerequisite file names generated from the pattern rule's prerequisite
>   patterns and the file name.

This is a little hard to follow, but basically when Make tries to build `run_paper_inc/b.py`, it looks for a pattern rule that matches `b.py`. The rule above doesn't fit. But this does:

```
%.py:
    $(subst run_,,$@)
```

**Second:**

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.pdf: ... $$(patsubst %, run_%, $$(wildcard $$*_inc/*.py))
    ...
```

One of Make's big shortcomings is its weak handling of wildcards. In this case `%` can't work for the pattern rule and the patsubst at the same time. But there's a way:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.pdf: ... $$(addprefix run_,$$(wildcard %_inc/*.py))
    ...
```

Comment: Ah, okay.  Testing this solution, it solves part of the problem, but not all of it.  Now, the different python files are run before the `pdflatex` command.  However, the python files are rerun whenever the latex file is recompiled.  To remedy this, I tried the following change.

    .SECONDEXPANSION
    %.pdf: ... $$(addsuffix run,$$(wildcard %_inc/*.py))
        ...

    %.pyrun: %.py
        $<

Since %.py is now a dependency of %.pyrun, I would expect this to only run the python program again the python file itself has changed, but instead it runs at each compile.

Comment: @MereInterest: if you don't want the python files run when you compile the latex file, why make them prerequisites? When *do* you want them run?

Comment: Wanting it to run prior to the latex file being compiled, but only if the python file has changed.  For example, I have a python script that makes a plot which is then included in the latex file.  If the python script has changed, then it should be run again in order to recreate the plot, but otherwise, the existing plot should be used.